# Can't update cache

Tags: 14.04, apt-cache

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I tried to update cache through Ubuntu terminal but it shows some error.I tried through software & updates in software center but after some downloads it failed . "please help"

Comment: Please post the actual output of `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update Ubuntu's internal list of available software packages and updates, please run the command UPDATE:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This should help, if this does not answer you question, please clarify your question and comment this answer to let me know. I hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to help, Trevor

Comment: ATTENTION! This command does **NOT** update ANY software! It does not work at all, because it would try to install a new package named "update", which does not exist. `sudo apt-get update` without the "install" would be better, as it at least refreshes Ubuntu's list of available packages and updates, but not actually installs them!

Comment: Note: The last edit (Revision 5) corrected the wrong command. But it still does not update the OS or its installed software packages, but only the list of available packages. If this is what the OP asked for, it's ok.

Comment: The op said my answer is what they wanted. So im not arguing.